How to solve "Import "rest_framework.views" not resolved" error after successfully installing the djangorestframework
I have just installed the djangorestframework in my Django project for the first time. Before installing all the required dependencies (djangorestframework being one of them), I created a virtual environment (venv) were my project can run.
Also I have created a virtual server where my project runs using Vagrant (ubuntu/bionic64).
I installed Django 3.2.10, django-rest-framework 3.12.4 and python 3.6.9
So after all this configurations when i try to import some classes from django-rest-framework and registered the "rest_framework" in INSTALLED_APPS in the settings.py, the imported commands are underlined using yellow lines. For example:
from rest_framework.views import APIview, the phrase "rest_framework" is underlined in yellow, what could be the problem?
I tried several solutions but that didn't

I re-installed the djangorestframe work package and tried to use it
Since sometimes your IDE can cache some data making it difficult for your rest_framework to run, so I re-   stared my IDE (Vs code)
I also restarted my PC in case it had any problem.
I changed my python interpreter to include the one with virtual environment but still did not work.
I tried to check for typos and resolved but the problem still persisted.


Share the full traceback. Are you sure you pointed to the correct virtual environment in the IDE?

Hi, could you please run django-admin help inside your project?

Ok, so that’s a configuration issue with your project in VSCode. It’s not an actual problem in your application.
it’s most likely related to the “Interpreter” configured for your project. You should be using the instance of Python that’s in your venv.
